Webpack bundle analyser is not working in the project with angular 18 version
I am working on angular 18 framework and I recently tried to integrate webpack bundle analyser in my project but it's giving me a weird error.I thought the issue is with my project so created a new dummy angular 18 project with angular cli and Tried there as well but the issue still remains.Tried exploring about it but didn't get any possible solution for the issue.
I simply installed the package in the project then ran ng build --stats-json which created stats.json file in dist/project name folder.
Now when I run the command to analyse this json file by going to the particular folder it is giving error.
I ran npx webpack-bundle-analyser stats.json and it gives error as:
can't analyse webpack bundle:
type error: cannot read properties of undefined reading filter.
I am referring the videos on YouTube to add this package but it is not working.

most likely with angular 18 you are using esbuild builder, not webpack. use source-map-explorer to analyze it insteaed

Can we configure source map explorer for development environment as well?

what do you mean? just build the project with development options or whichever configuration you want, just sourcemaps options should be on. then use the tool to analyze
